# How to return 404 page if illegal character in path error is met in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC application, I have my own error handling module which look like:

```
public class ErrorHandlingModule : IHttpModule
{
      public void Init( HttpApplication context )
      {
         context.Error += Context_Error;
      }

      public void Dispose() { }

      void Context_Error( object sender, EventArgs e ) { }

}
```

There I treat different type of exceptions like `HttpException` and other type of custom exceptions.

I want to check if `Illegal characters in path` exception is met then returns 404 page. (like an user insert `http://www.website.com/test"`)

By default returns 500 error page.

What's the better way to do this ? By comparing with exception's message, by `HRESULT` ... ?

Answer (score 0):

You simply change the Status of your HttpResponse to NotFound (404):

```
Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
```

You can get the response from the current context, `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse`.

If you are trying to capture a bad incoming request - that is, the URI of the request has invalid path characters - you will have to fight WCF or reconfigure it to get that information, as it is processed by the chain of message handlers before it is ever dispatched to your application.

Comment: My question is how to detect that exception, not returns 404 error... I want for that mentioned in title error , to redirect 404 page.

Comment: How did you get `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse` ?? I don't have WCF !!! I have ASP.NET MVC